# Excel - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, export, cells

Is there any way to mark specific cells in Excel and automatically export them to a Google Spreadsheet. Don't want to export the whole document, only specific cells.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you want to export and then copy/paste them to a new Google Spreadsheet.

Or

Import entire sheet and delete what you don't want.

Comment: do you expect something to automatically guess which cells you want? I mean there has to be some level of manual work you are doing with this. Are you having to do this with a lot of similar spreadsheets which all need the same cells imported?